# How to write ORM for abstract class as a superclass (No annotations)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I have a class called ***User.java*** and it has a list of activities.
***Activity.java*** is an abstract class extended by ***Dance.java*** and ***Drawing.java***

```
    public class User {
        private UserKey userKey; // PK (UserKey is another embeddable class and has a string userId)
        private List<Activity> activities;
        
        //some more fields and getter setters
    }
```

```
    public abstract class Activity {
        // has nothing. I can add ID field if needed.
    }
```

```
    public class Dance extends Activity {
     private DanceKey danceKey; // PK. DanceKey is another embeddable class and has a string danceId.
     private String danceName;
     // some more fields and getter setters
    }
```

```
    public class Drawing extends Activity {
     private DrawingKey drawingKey; // PK. DrawingKey is another embeddable class and has a string drawingId.
     private String drawingName;
     // some more fields and getter setters
    }
```

Following are the orm files:

user.orm.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <entity-mappings version="2.5"
        xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_orm_2_5.xsd">
        <entity name="User" class="com.app001.demo.User">
            <table name="USER" />
            <attributes>
                 <embedded-id attribute-type="com.app001.demo.UserKey" name="userKey">
                     <attribute-override name="key">
                        <column name="USER_ID"/>
                     </attribute-override>
                 </embedded-id>
                
                <!-- what do i put here for list of activities-->
                 
            </attributes>
        </entity>
    </entity-mappings>
```

dance.orm.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <entity-mappings version="2.5"
        xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_orm_2_5.xsd">
        <entity name="Dance" class="com.app001.demo.Dance">
            <table name="DANCE" />
            <attributes>
                 <embedded-id attribute-type="com.app001.demo.DanceKey" name="danceKey">
                     <attribute-override name="key">
                        <column name="DANCE_ID"/>
                     </attribute-override>
                 </embedded-id>
                 <basic attribute-type="java.lang.String" name="danceName">
                            <column name="DANCE_NAME"/>
                 </basic>
            </attributes>
        </entity>
    </entity-mappings>
```

drawing.orm.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <entity-mappings version="2.5"
        xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_orm_2_5.xsd">
        <entity name="Drawing" class="com.app001.demo.Drawing">
            <table name="DRAWING" />
            <attributes>
                 <embedded-id attribute-type="com.app001.demo.DrawingKey" name="drawingKey">
                     <attribute-override name="key">
                        <column name="DRAWING_ID"/>
                     </attribute-override>
                 </embedded-id>
                 <basic attribute-type="java.lang.String" name="drawingName">
                            <column name="DRAWING_NAME"/>
                 </basic>
            </attributes>
        </entity>
    </entity-mappings>
```

activity.orm.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <entity-mappings version="2.5"
        xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_orm_2_5.xsd">
        
        <!-- what do i put here for activity-->
```

I tried these approaches:

1. In activity.orm.xml, if i make Activity.java as `<mapped-superclass>` , this doesnt work because i am not allowed to enter any `<inheritance-strategy>` along with `<mapped-superclass>`
2. In activity.orm.xml , if i mark Activity.java as `<entity>` and `<inheritance_strategy>` as ***TABLE_PER_CLASS*** or ***JOINED*** i get following error:
   *During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST*

Please let me know how can i write ORM for activity.orm.xml for my case.
***Note*** that i cannot alter java code much. I can may be add an id in Activity.java if needed.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it will have one discriminator column for the type of activity'? What should happen if you set `List.of(new Dance(), new Gaming(), new Drawing())` to `User.activities`?

Comment: Please ignore the discriminator column part. It was wrong understanding at my end. 
As per your question, if we store multiple activities for one user then ideally each activity will go in its own table and it would have user_id as foreign key. But since there is an abstract class (Activity.java) between User and Dance/Gaming/Drawing tables , i am not sure on how to write ORM for Activity abstract class. Please note that i cannot change the java code much

Comment: What have you tried so far? The safest strategy to use would be [joined inheritance](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Joined,_Multiple_Table_Inheritance) (you'll need at least the id property to go to the base entity). You might want to try out [table per class](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Table_Per_Class_Inheritance) as well; not sure how well Hibernate handles one-to-many associations in such a scenario, though

Comment: I added one id attribute in ***Activity*** class. Marked inheritance strategy as Table_per_class in *activity.orm.xml*. Created one dance object and set it into User.activities and then did ```em.persist(user)``` got following error : *During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST*. Any idea?

Comment: @crizzis i have edited the entire question to make my issue more clear. Please take a look.

Comment: 'During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST' - this means you put a new (transient) object in `User.activities`. You need to either call `em.persist()` on the new dance object first or use `cascade = PERSIST` with `@OneToMany`